# How can I use Google Map Api with a Rom which simplify Google framework?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to use Google map for some LBS Apps.But some Android Rom simplify Google Framework and they can hardly install Google Play or Google Maps.SO I want to know is there anyway to let my apps include the function of Google Framework?Maybe like add some files in my app.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Google Maps for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) introduction, Google Maps for Android relies on [Google Play services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html). This means that you must be on a phone that has Google Play installed.

Comment: Yes,thank you.So you mean that there is not anyway to install google play services by my app.What a pity!